# I want to connect raspberry pi and alexa in order to control my Samsung tv

Tags: pi-3b+

i have amazon alexa and i cant control my Samsung tv model UE50KU6000W.
 Somewhere i can't recall i think that i read that you can do it if you use raspberry pi. So is that true? and if so how can i do that?
So i have Samsung tv, amazon Alexa and my raspberry pi3 b+ and i want to open, close my tv and etc.

I want to use my raspbery pi with raspbian, retropie and also use it as connection with amazon alexa.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Please note that users may choose to downvote a question if they think it is unclear or fails to convey that the OP did their own research. That said, there is usually little to be gained to discuss why a question was downvoted and by whom (it's not necessarily the user that posts a comment).

Comment: google 'raspberry pi hdmi cec' to control your tv from your pi

Comment: you can also control the TV by WiFi as a wireless remote control

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely likely, but it's not something you could do without getting a bit nitty gritty. Some users have downvoted your question; this is because your question is rather open-ended; a little Googling might help before you ask.

As it stands, there are methods of accessing Alexa with a Raspi - you can easily create your own app that accesses [Alexa APIs](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa) if you register for Amazon Developer.

I'm not entirely sure on the exact solution to controlling the Samsung, as it depends on the exact model and software available, and can be a little finnicky at times.

*However*, one tried-and-tested method is to take the thing you've got - the remote itself. It's extremely likely to be an infra-red controller, something you could probably analyse the patterns of with an IR camera and then communicate to the TV with an IR LED on your Raspi.

This might take some effort, though - if the IR patterns don't exist online, you'd probably have to figure them out manually. Alternatively, you could put the remote in a steady position relative to the camera and record and mirror the IR output of a certain pixel on the remote LED for each button. Either way, by having a direct-to-remote method of access, you would be able to easily automate certain controls, though they'd be limited by how quick the TV's UI is, of course, and you'd need to hook up a camera or similar to read data from the TV display (eg volume, channel).

It's undoubtedly a bit more than a weekend project, but there's nothing stopping you from making an automated remote if the Samsung APIs don't exist, and if they do you could try your luck on those. Either way, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for the project in question:
https://github.com/eclair4151/AlexaControlledSamsungTV/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.